# Unable to connect to internet

Tags: 12.10, internet-connection

I just upgraded to 12.10. Everything appears to go well but I am unable to connect to the Internet. The LAN is fine and I can view my shared files but no e-mail or access to web pages. My other computer which is running 12.04 or older seems to connect fine. I only upgraded one to make sure things would be ok. I am currently connecting fine with a wireless Windows laptop.

Output from cat /etc/resolv.conf

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: If you want to ask a question about the hard disk, I would start a [new post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to see what you are connected to first. you could  use

```
ifconfig
```

and see if you get an IP adress. If you do try

```
ping 173.194.67.94
```

to ping a google server, if this works the routing works okay.
Then test

```
ping www.google.com
```

to see if that can be resolved to the right server ip address.

If you can't connect to the internet you'll probably find your problem somewhere in these steps. Then compare the network settings between your two systems to see what is going on.

If you've installed 12.10 somewhat weird like I did(minimal install without gui) you might want to check the /etc/network/interfaces and remove everything but your local interface. This is what made my computer get this problem a few days ago.

Comment: I think the ping 173.194.67.94 worked. output was continuous lines of 64 bytes from 173.194.67.94 icmp_req=52 ttl=45 time=108 ms

Comment: I think the ping 173.194.67.94 worked. output was continuous lines of 64 bytes from 173.194.67.94 icmp_req=52 ttl=45 time=108 ms The ping www.google.com returned ping:unknown host www.google.com

Comment: FWIW I just clicked on the update to 12.10 button from 12.04 on update manager

Comment: ok, you probably have a problem with your dns configuration, in ubuntu desktop when you're using network-manager for the configuration of your pc you should have a nearly empty /etc/network/interfaces file, you can check it by outputting it contents in a terminal (cat /etc/network/interfaces) if 12.04 worked correctly it probably doesn't say anything about eth0 or wlan0 which is good. So then go to the network manager and see if there is something underneath wired network. this should be autoconfigured. At the bottom using edit connections you can edit this. Good luck!

Comment: output from cat /etc/network/interfaces  auto lo     iface lo inet loopback

Comment: Luck may be what I need, still no internet but LAN is fine

Comment: I am unable to connect to the LAN at this point

Comment: I went to /etc/network/interfaces/ and cleaned it out. On reboot it looked for the network configuration and could not find it. It loaded without network manager.

Comment: The cat /etc/network/interfaces is fine for use with network manager. maybe try to connect to the internet in the dirty way by following the directions for a dynamic ip on this page https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/network-configuration.html after that run ubuntu and upgrade your software over the internet after that.

Comment: I tried without success. I ended up with No DHCPOFFERS received No working leases in persistent database - sleeping

Answer (score 1):

I meant to post this as comment but I don;t have privileges for that.

resolv.conf must have at least 1 non-local entry for packet routing. Click on the network indicator in the system tray, then click Edit Connections->[Choose your connection (wired or wifi)]-> Edit -> IPv4 settings.

Make sure that the "Method" dropdown shows exactly this value "Automatic". If you set your own DNS servers manually, make sure that the values that you see are identical on both your computers. If you make any changes, save your connection, disconnect and reconnect again to generate a new resolv.conf.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. It is a wired connection. I have it set to Automatic. I saved, disconnected, reconnected and still no internet.

Comment: I also rebooted the router for good measure and still no internet

Comment: Somehow i have succeded in not being able to connect at all. I now cannot connect to the local network or internet.Any chance of restoring my network connection?

Comment: Are the settings identical on the updated computer as well as the older one? I should have called that out more clearly in the original response...

Comment: All of the settings are the same. I use Automatic (DHCP) routinely to make things easier. At the moment I cant even connect to the LAN and I can't get an IP from the router for some reason. Really starting to regret hitting the upgrade button.

Comment: Not sure if this helps but after rebooting this morning and checking the settings a box popped uo saying "Failure to download extra data files" flashplugin-installer  Not sure if this helps but it looks like my uprage didn't install correctly

Comment: Yes, pretty sure your upgrade got stuck somewhere. Without logs, it will be near impossible for me to triage this further. A safe bet is to create a start up USB stick, boot using that stick, then run repair installation using the steps mentioned [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery)

Comment: That is what I did end almost everything is working ok. I'm able to connect to the internet. I still have issues with the usb cradle on Golden Cheetah but that will be a new question in the future. I really regret hitting that update button. 12.04 was finally working well for me.

Comment: Glad that worked for you. My upgrade experience was quite different from yours, obviously :-)